# PayPals date format confuses strtotime(). What can I do?

Tags: php, paypal, timezone, strtotime

PayPals IPN sends dates in this format `08:29:40 Aug 06, 2012 PDT`

When I run it through `strtotime()` I get this in response `1344266980`

When this goes through `date()` I get `2012-08-40 16:29:40`.

What's happening and how can I fix it.

The timezone is set in PHP to `Europe/London`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your date format string must be wrong. Are you by any chance calling `date` like so:

```
date("Y-m-s H:i:s",$time)
```

If so, it should be `Y-m-d` - quite possibly a typo.

Reason I say this is because it's simply impossible for `date()` to return `40` for the day number.

Comment: Yeh that's what I thought with the 40. But the typo passed me. I used "s" instead of "d" :/